# Create MosaicDataset with 12 Bits

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, mosaic

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1, and I want to create a mosaic dataset, but my rasters are in 12 bits, and a mosaic doesn't have this option.

What can I do?

Comment: Create a 16-bit mosaic?

Comment: i did it, is a only option

Comment: The base data doesn't change, and there isn't any precision loss, and overviews are always GeoTIFF (which doesn't support 12-bit), so it's not a very restrictive choice.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Vince in comments, you could try to:

> Create a 16-bit mosaic ... The base data doesn't change, and there
>   isn't any precision loss, and overviews are always GeoTIFF (which
>   doesn't support 12-bit), so it's not a very restrictive choice.